# Prevent direct access to my server using reverse proxy

Tags: linux, web-server, azure, reverse-proxy, local-area-network

I have a web server setup in *Microsoft Azure* and it has a domain name associated with it like `www.example.com`. This web server is very critical and i don't want anyone other than 1 or two people to know the exact URL or its IP. I believe direct access to this web server will be a huge security threat and want to prevent the my workers from accessing it directly.

*Why a restriction in needed ?*

- Prevent direct access
- I don't want my workers to access my web server outside my office.

Even with these restrictions applied i want one or two people still be able to access this web server directly (in case of any emergency).

*My thoughts*

Setup a reverse proxy at my office. Allow workers to access to my web server like if the web server is located on our local network.

So, when users type

```
172.16.10.1 <---> Reverse Proxy <---> www.example.com
```

I'm sure whether what i plan to do is possible or not. If you have any other ideas please do let me know.

[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zwve.png)

Currently i have not setup to prevent the direct access. I have not tried anything.

**EDIT**

*I cannot restrict access to my web server using IP (There are other reasons of this)*

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot restrict access to my web server using IP (There are other
>   reasons of this)

Security by obscurity never works. Lots of hostile entities constantly scan the internet for (vulnerable) hosts, so even if you don't publish the exact URL or IP address somewhere, it can still be found (and since you are using a public cloud, it **will** be found).

> So, when users type
>
> > 172.16.10.1 <---> Reverse Proxy <---> www.example.com
>
> I'm sure whether what i plan to do is possible or not. If you have any
>   other ideas please do let me know.

You are only trying to solve how you would expose your service to your internal users, not addressing your security concern at all.

There is no way around this unless you restrict at the network level, which is still the best approach for consuming a resource located in a public cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If only few people should access a server, why is it on the public Internet? Trying to hide the domain and the IP address doesn't stop automated attacks going randomly through all the public IP addresses. Information on the top secret domain name is also likely to leak. This is not a suitable approach for a critical service.

Naturally you could use a firewall to only allow connection from the public IP address(es) of your office network, but Azure has a better alternative: with the [Azure Virtual Network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) there's no need for the server to have a public IP address at all. Instead, the server would be accessible through a site-to-site VPN from the office LAN, using a private IP address. This makes a virtual server on the cloud act like you had an on-premises server.

Comment: I will definitely check out AVN but i have few questions. I cannot restrict access by IP or IP ranges. Will i be able to setup a site to site VPN between my public web server to my office LAN directly ?

Comment: Will i be able to setup a reverse proxy like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zwve.png) ? Setting up a reverse proxy is much easier than setting up S2S VPN.

Answer (score 0):

You can move in two direction:

1. Setup up a firewall for allow outbound traffic on port 80/443 only to selected IP range
2. Set up a Basic Authentication from the webserver.
3. Setup a VPN: proxy your network traffic trough a VPN

The second solution is password based, so every user that need to gain the access need to authenticate using user:pass (no db is necessary).

With the first solution, no one can connect if they are not allowed to interact with the server (firewall based)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I already have basic authentication setup in my web server. I cannot restrict access to my web server using IP ranges.

Comment: yes you can setup a vpn

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a VPN from your on-prem network to your Azure network
2. Which reverse proxy are you using? With F5 you can use an APM to limit who can access the site

Answer (score 0):

You could update DNS to a c-name record and redirect to it use an application layer load balancer like application gateway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a network security group (nsg)
2. Bind nsg to your web server nic or subset
3. Restrict by ip and port

So much cleaner and more secure than proposed option.

OR other options

1. Is your reverse proxy a netscaler by any chance? You can use it as an rdp gateway
2. Do you have a published Citrix or terminal services environment? You could publish an rdp connection in there